# @pointcut doesn't work right

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I realy get dangle.
This code works fine:

```
@Before("execution(* *.runi(..))")
public void perform()
{
    sysout("hello");    
}
```

but this get exception:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.runi(..))")
public void perform()
{

}

@Before("perform()")
public void singerReport(Name name)
{
    sysout("hello");    
}
```

exception:

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's telling you that argument "name" is unbound. Remove the argument, and the two should work identically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use somefing like:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.runi(com.yourproject.Name)) && args(name)")
public void perform(Name name){}

@Before("perform(com.yourproject.Name) && args(name)")
public void singerReport(Name name)
{
   sysout("hello");    
}
```